# tbl_summary() with long, tidy data where single (e.g.,) patient ID has multiple values in factor column

Tags: r, gtsummary

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(gtsummary)

    tibble(patient_id = c("A","A", "A", "B", "B"), 
           disease = c("cancer", "heart disease", "fat fingers", "heart disease", "fat fingers")) %>% 
      select(-patient_id) %>% 
      tbl_summary()
```

[image]

The above is example code and output from the `tbl_summary` function from the gtsummary library.

I've got two patients in this case (A and B) and would like to see the output showing what percentage of the patients have "fat fingers" (should be 100%), what percentage have "heart disease" (should be 100%) and what percentage have cancer (should be 50%), and I'd also like the "N" to be equal to 2.

Within tbl_summary() I can't see that there's an option to summarise by an id column, for example, so the only other option I have would be to `pivot_wider(id_cols = patient_id, values_from....etc.)`, but then the tbl_summary() output wouldn't have the nice headings and sub-headings. Other than that, I guess I can just make a custom gt table from scratch, but I like the ease of tbl_summary(), it just doesn't appear to work well when there's more than one factor value per id.

Comment: can you show expected table output?

Comment: Sorry, I should have done so rather than just explain it in prose. Faniel D Sjobery has the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical gtsummary table does expect the data in wide format. But you can get the table you need. You'll start by adding rows for patients without the listed disease, and then you can summarize with `tbl_summary()`. You'll need to make a few aesthetic modifications as well. Example below!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tbl <- 
  tibble(patient_id = c("A","A", "A", "B", "B"), 
       disease = c("cancer", "heart disease", "fat fingers", 
                   "heart disease", "fat fingers"), 
       present = TRUE) %>%
  # adding observations for patients without a disease
  complete(patient_id, disease, fill = list(present = FALSE)) %>%
  select(-patient_id) %>% 
  # summarizing data
  tbl_summary(by = present, percent = "row") %>%
  modify_header(stat_2 ~ "**Overall**") %>%
  modify_column_hide(stat_1)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful, many thanks Daniel for your wonderful package - it is a joy to use and I will make sure I cite - and for the answer: This works beautifully. My example includes only two patients with one factor over which I'm summarizing, but in the real world I'm going to have many more patients (1K - 170K), and will be wanting to summarise over many more factors - up to 10, perhaps at least - and I think that `complete()` will quite rapidly result in very very large datasets. I suppose I could separate the analysis out and use `tbl_stack()`?

Comment: You can stack them, for sure. You could also pivot to a wide dataset? That could also be slow, however.