# Can I specify a custom denominator in tbl_summary()?

Tags: r, gtsummary

This is an extension to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945155/tbl-summary-with-long-tidy-data-where-single-e-g-patient-id-has-multiple)

in words: given two groups, and unique purchases for each member of a group, what is the frequency and percentage within that group?

**Group 1 = Senior**
Abby buys apples, bananas
Betty buys bananas
group size = 2, frequency of apples is 1, percentage (50%), frequency of bananas is 2(100%)

**Group 2 = no_discount**
Charlie buys apples, bananas
Dave buys apples
Eric buys apples, bananas
group size = 3, freq of apples = 3 (100%), bananas = 2(66%)

Toy data: generate two groups, with fixed membership, and create purchases of different fruit types.

```
set.seed(5400)
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

produce  <- c("apples", "bananas", "cherries", "dill", "eclairs", "figs")
people <- (1:75)

#generate repeat people with random purchase
df <- tibble(ID = sample(people, 100, replace = TRUE), 
             fruit = as.factor(sample(produce, 100, replace = TRUE)), 
             )

df <- unique(df)   #no repeats for customer and fruit purchase

# assign unique discount status to a unique person
df <-df |> mutate(discount = case_when(ID %% 2 == 0 ~ "no_discount", 
                                    .default =  "senior"))


# shows the count for fruit type by group 
df |>
  group_by(discount, fruit) %>%
  summarize(Freq=n())
```

The `no_discount` group has 28 people, the `senior` group has 27.  There are 55 unique people, and only their unique fruit purchases are shown.  This part is correct, with a frequency of fruit type overall and a denominator of 55 people.

```
df$present <- TRUE

df |>  complete(ID, fruit, fill = list(present = FALSE)) %>%
  select(-ID) %>% 
  # summarizing data
  tbl_summary(by = present, percent = "row") |>
  modify_header(stat_2 ~ "**Overall**") %>%
  modify_column_hide(stat_1)
```

I tried these methods to look at the in-group frequencies and percentages.  The frequencies are correct, but the percentages are not.  The percentages should be calculated using the number of people in each group for the denominator (28 for `no_discount`, 27 for `senior`).   Instead, it uses the number of observations in each group as the denominator, and I want to change the denominator.

```
df$present <- TRUE
df |> select(-ID) |>
  na.omit() |>
  tbl_strata(
    strata = discount, ~ .x |>
      tbl_summary(by = present, percent = "cell")) 


df |>  complete(ID, fruit, fill = list(present = FALSE)) %>%
  select(-ID) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
     strata = discount, 
     ~ .x |>
  # summarizing data
  tbl_summary(by = present, percent = "column") ) 
  #modify_header(stat_2 ~ "**Overall**") %>%
  #modify_column_hide(stat_1)
```

There's too much data in the real example to make this into the wide format.  Currently, I'm using excel to calculate the correct frequencies using the specific group denominator.

Thanks for any assistance!

In this photo, the N for TRUE is used as the denominator for the percentages. I'd like to make that N the number of people in each group (28 for no_discount, 27 for seniors).  So instead of 7/47 = 15%, I was hoping to have 7/28 =25%.

[image]

Comment: This is **no** improvement to your previous deleted question.

Comment: The documentation is the first place I looked, the second place was here and I still don't see how to fix the denominators to represent number in the group. That's the question: denominators are wrong, how to fix?

Comment: 1. The denominators are not wrong, you're just looking to use the function in a way that is was not designed for. 2. There is no straightforward way to get what you're looking for, and you'll probably have better luck constructing your way from scratch. 3. If you're set on using `tbl_summary()`, you could probably get what you're after by only showing the `n` from `tbl_summary()`. Then followup with two calls to `add_stat()` to add modified percentages. Lastly, two calls to `modify_column_merge()` could be used to put the n and percent in a single cell.

Comment: I'm not set on using a particular way. A better title would have been the one that's there now but when I posted the question the first time, I don't think I was clear about the problem I was having and was trying to clarify that. I added a picture - the issue is that the values for TRUE are being used as the denominator, but I wanted the denominators to be the group size My real dataset will be at the multigig size, so making it wide wasn't a good option. Thanks for even looking at this question, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in case anyone else has this question: the key thing is to make the data wide, not long.  Then it sorts itself out, because the package works best with the data in a wide format.